# Mapping software

Tags: mapping

I'm looking for software for producing a web based map of some 200 - 300 location in Britain. The major requirements are customisable pop up boxes will will scale efficiently on a mobile and contain images. I have tried google maps (see https://mapsengine.google.com/map/viewer?mid=zihxiZSq-Gvk.kU35oasm4XDo click on Norwich for example) but this clearly does not work well in a web browser let alone on a mobile.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you don’t want to provide/create the map, but add locations to an existing map? // Would a static image be okay, or is it required to be able to browse the map? // Do you want to be able to include the map on your webpage? // Price/license restrictions?

Comment: What platforms do you need to be supported? I might have a nice solution for Android. As it works via `.kmz` files, it also plays fine with e.g. Google Earth. Might require some hand-work for "customized pop-up boxes" (I did exactly that, basically creating my own "travel guide"). Does that sound like a potential match?

Comment: Possibly related - http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26691/free-angular-js-map-of-the-uk

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I am switching from google maps to OSMN and Leaflet, but Leaflet sizes its popups as pixels, not percentages.

Comment: OP not seen since posting 5 years ago, so unlikely to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will satisfy all your requirements, but [Open Street Map](http://openstreetmap.org/) is an open source mapping package that may help.

You can add your own points of interest to existing maps and display maps on various devices.

Comment: Works very good. Explanation and further reading here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_Track_example