# Free (Angular) Js map of the UK

Tags: gratis, angularjs, mapping

I am looking for a map of the United Kingdom which recognizes clicks on each part of the map (Europe, other areas a bonus, but won't weight too heavily on my intital choice).

I would prefer resolution at least to county level and major cities would be a bonus. More granularity is not required, although I don't object to it being there.

Customization would be welcome: labeling, re-sizing, maybe the ability to change each area's colour depending on `$scope` variables (a sort of heat map) ...

The more features, the merrier, but I will take anything that I can get.

At the very simplest, just an outline of the UK with some form of data to determine each of the counties on the map.

Must be free for commercial use, just in case I sell a dozen or more copies of my £0.99 app :-)

---

[Update] Since no one seems to know of an AngularJs solution, I could live with plain JS.

Comment: I take it you've looked at the Ordnance Survey: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products-grid.html

Comment: Interesting (+1), but not all free and doesn't seem to have what I am looking for. At most, I might be able to put **a lot** of effort into "Boundary line" from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html  I am still searching, but might have to accept his if nothing else turns up. Thanks.